# Replicating to 3 databases one is web server

Tags: replication, sql-server-2016, cloud

I have a customer that is looking for a very unusual replication configuration. I am hoping for some insight on why this is a bad idea, or even the possibility that it can be done.

There are two systems where replication will be deployed, Publisher and Distributor will replicate to Subscriber on a local LAN. Need to populate a cloud server for web site.

**Question1:** Could this subscriber become a publisher to another cloud based subscriber? Before you point out that the original publisher can update both local and cloud subscribers, customer doesn't want the work load on publisher system.

**Question 2:** Customer suggested sending backup of local subscriber to cloud and restoring on cloud DB server at least daily. I don't believe permissions are replicated, along with other issues. Comments?

I could go on and on, but I will wait on any feedback before going further.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use a Subscriber to re-publish data to other Subscribers, as briefly mentioned in [**Replication Publishing Model Overview - Subscribers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/replication-publishing-model-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#subscribers). I'm not sure under what scenarios this is applicable or not.

   Though one thing your customer should keep in mind is just because they are not putting the publishing workload on the original Publisher, doesn't mean there can't be contention caused from the Subscriber doing the re-publishing. Depending on the timing of things, and if other changes are actively being made to the tables at the Subscriber concurrent to changes being replicated from the original Publisher, there could be lock contention that affects the original Publisher's server in *some* capacity.
2. Server level settings, such as **Logins**, their database mappings, and server level permissions won't be included in the database backup, but database level settings such as **Users** will be. Though most times this will result in orphaned accounts, even if the **Login** is manually created at the destination server where the backup is restored. This is because each **Login** has a unique `SID` which correlates to the **User**.

   The [**Troubleshoot orphaned users (SQL Server)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/troubleshoot-orphaned-users-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15?) documentation goes into good detail on identifying and resolving this issue.

Comment: Thank you the reply, I am reviewing the links.